# Getting a remainder in the last iteration of for loop with range

Tags: python, for-loop

```
chunk = 100
size = 253
for start in range(0, size, chunk):
      print((start, chunk))
```

This prints out:

```
(0, 100)
(100, 100)
(200, 100)
```

but what I want is

```
(0, 100)
(100, 100)
(200, 53)
```

I could of course check each iteration if the remainder is less than the chunk size but maybe there is a more elegant way

Comment: If your issue has been resolved, don't forget to close the question by accepting the right answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Assuming size is greater than chunk):

```
chunk=100
size=253
for start in range(0,size, chunk):
    print (start,chunk)

if size % chunk:
    print(size, size % chunk)
```

It makes sure that if `size` is not a multiple of `chunk`, then it will print the left over part of your last chunk.

You can also use `else` with the for loop but it won't work if size is a multiple of chunk! Then, you need to check again in else block which makes it no the best solution.

**EDIT:**

It's not appriopriate to change your question once people has answered it.

Consider reviewing the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

I don't understand completely what you want to achieve. I am assuming if size is a multiple of chunk, then you want to print the chunk along with start and if it doesn't, then size % chunk.

I am using `[:-1]` to iterate and leave the last element and then I use else part of for loop to decide what to print.

```
chunk=100
size=253
for start in range(0, size, chunk)[:-1]:
    print(start,chunk)
else:
    print(start+chunk, size % chunk if size % chunk else chunk)
```

If you want to print `zero` if size is a multiple of chunk, then change the last statement to `print(start+chunk, size % chunk)`.

Output:

```
0 100
100 100
200 53
```

**EDIT:**

As pointed out by @user3840170 in the comment section of this answer. It's better to not to use `else` block with the for loop for your problem statement. The intention of using an else block with a for loop is when you want to execute a particular piece of code when your for loop was prematurely terminated using a `break` statement.

Comment: I have edited my question so it will be more clear I don't need the (200,100)

Comment: It's not appriopriate to change your question once people has answered it. Anyway check my answer!

Comment: This is a wrong answer. The `else` block doesn't run if the loop body invokes `break`.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Can you see any `break` condition in my for loop? Have you tried the above code and check where it was failing?

Comment: Oh, I realised it's not actually a problem; if the loop body ever invokes `break`, it means the block is in fact not intended to run. Still, I think writing a separate generator is more idiomatic and less prone to repeating the loop body.

Comment: Agree. My first example used a separate `if` construct after the for loop and then I showed another way to do the same thing to the OP. I will add your comment as a remark in my answer. However, it still solves the OP problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to check before printing if the size - start is smaller than chunk:

```
chunk=100
size=253
for start in range(0,size, chunk):
    if size - start < chunk:
        print(start, abs(start - size))
    else:
        print (start,chunk)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own generator function and use it instead of `range`:

```
def chunks(start, end, max_size):
    current = start
    while current < end:
        chunk_size = min(max_size, end - current)
        yield (current, chunk_size)
        current += chunk_size
```

To take your example:

```
chunk = 100
size = 253
for start, size in chunks(0, chunk, size):
    print((start, size))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `chunk < size`, you can anticipate the last iteration and feed it into the `else` clause in the for loop:

```
for start in range(0, size - chunk, chunk):
    print(start, chunk)
else:
    print(start + chunk, size % chunk)
```

It is probably not the best design to maintain though.

Comment: Those nicks :D (Check OP's). Btw, the `else` should check if `chunk` "fits" `size`, otherwise there will be some strange output at the end.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed ;) Right, I assumed `chunk` is a portion of `size`, hence logically could not exceed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for start in range(0, size - chunk, chunk): 
    print(start, chunk) 
else: 
    if size % chunk: 
        print(start + chunk, size % chunk)
```